# database in iphone

Tags: iphone

What is sqlite3_prepare_v2 statement?
why we write this BOVE STATEMENT?
tell me different parameters for sqlite3_prepare_v2.

Answer (score 2):

See the C/C++ Interface For SQLite Version 3:
[Compiling An SQL Statement](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_prepare)